# XPath for child element with conditions on parent's other children?

Tags: xml, xpath

I want to find out the XPath query for the XML code where the element i.e. `city` which is to be checked for a condition (whether it is equal to e.g. 'New York') is nested and the required element i.e. `bprice` is not nested.

Here's the XML code:

```
<book>
<btitle>The Inferno</btitle>
<bprice currency = "dollars">19.99</bprice>
<bdate>2013-05-14</bdate>
<authorinfo>
    <lastname>Brown</lastname>
    <midname>G.</midname>
    <firstname>Dan</firstname>
</authorinfo>
<publisherinfo>
    <publishername>Doubleday</publishername>
    <street>1745 Broadway</street>
    <city>New York</city>
    <zip>11119</zip>
    <country>USA</country>
</publisherinfo>
</book>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This XPath,

```
/book[publisherinfo/city = 'New York']/bprice
```

will select those `bprice` elements within `book` elements whose `publisherinfo/city` element has a string value of `"New York"`, as requested.